# Could not resolve dependencies for spark

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I m trying to build a local version of spark. I made some modification with the code, and nothing to do with maven.

I had this issue:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spark-sketch_2.12: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.spark:spark-sketch_2.12:jar:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.12:jar:tests:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots) -> [Help 1]
```

I compiled the project with:

```
build/mvn -Dmaven.test.skip clean package
```

Can somebody let me know how to fix this?

Comment: can you undo the changes and see it if builds and also try to make sure that all the dependencies are resolved. You could also close the IDE and start it again. Also make sure that you are not behind any firewall as sometimes that could also cause an issue like this.

Comment: Did you download the spark source code and you are trying to build "your spark" or do you have another project that uses Spark?

Comment: Do you really need SNAPSHOT versions of spark? It's highly likely that the version is not available as you see...

Comment: You should use the version 3.1.0 instead of 3.1.0-SNAPSHOT see https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sketch_2.12